# Rails 5: show selected value at edit action with JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

In View I have drop-down, where User can be selected:

```
   <!-- more code above -->
<% for role in user.roles %>
<div class="col-sm-10"><select class="form-control m-b" name="users" id="user_list">
   <option value="<%= user.id %>" data-edit-url="<%= edit_common_role_path(role.id) %>"><%= user.name %></option>
```

This **JS** script on select, opens role of selected User by role ID for edit (e.g., */common/roles/1/edit*)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
            edit = $('#user_list').change(function() {
            window.location = $(this).find(":selected").data('edit-url');
            });
</script>
```

**How to achieve that when Edit path is opened, in drop-down menu selected User name is shown?**  At the moment it always get 1st value in list. I'm on Rails 5, Bootstrap. Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of rails. But, can you cross check once if you it is **edit-url** not **data-edit-url**.

And also instead of `$(this).find(":selected").data('edit-url');` simply use `$(this).data('edit-url')`.

I have a small working example in Plain HTML and Jquery.

```
<html>

<head>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.js"   
        integrity="sha256-16cdPddA6VdVInumRGo6IbivbERE8p7CQR3HzTBuELA="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>    
</head>

<body>

    <select id="url">
        <option value="Please Select">1</option>
        <option value="https://google.com">2</option>        
    </select>

</body>

<script>

    $('#url').change(function(){
                     window.location = $(this).val();
                     });

</script>    


</html>
```

I hope, it will help.

Comment: Thank you, however this does not work for me. Any of suggested changes does not allow to open Edit path on drop-down select.

Comment: Can you tell me what is the URL being formed ?

Comment: My edit url is `/common/roles/1/edit` for editing role with ID=1  When I did changes you suggested, basically nothing happened.

Comment: Have you tried replacing `$(this).data('edit-url');` instead of `$(this).find(":selected").data('edit-url');` ?

Comment: Yes and there is no difference in result - it still loads in 1st value from list.

Comment: `window.location = $('option:selected', this).attr('edit-url');` try this? OR `window.location = $('option:selected', this).attr('data-edit-url');`

Comment: First does error, secont version performs Edit action, however still it shows 1st value from drop-down, not which was selected (e.g., 3rd with url `/common/roles/3/edit` )

Comment: can you paste rendered HTML of your select element for me?

Comment: I pasted it here - [link](http://paste.ofcode.org/6NUkGMUUrtvs9M98mdJGq3)

Comment: [Sorry, here will be the whole picture](http://paste.ofcode.org/WTsLnZzQqQci5yp9QgDq7v)

Comment: Yeah :D That's much better. I will have look. Thanks

Comment: Instead of `/common/roles/1/edit` and `/common/roles/3/edit` simply use `common/roles/1/edit` and `common/roles/1/edit` in your `data-edit-url` attribute.

Comment: Your dropdown is working just fine. Issue is with the way you are specifying redirecting location.

Comment: I'm using `edit_common_role_path(role.id)` which is Rails named route... basically I cannot do it differently. Are you sure this is the case?

Comment: Yeah, I am sure. I have run your code by making changes and redirection is working properly. Problem is `/` changes the context path of your application and it is not a valid input to `window.location`. As per my undersanding `edit_common_role_path(role.id)` rail route is a kind of function returning this value. If possible change the value which is being returned by `edit_common_role_path(role.id)`

Comment: In case you can't change `edit_common_role_path(role.id)` then replace `window.location = $('option:selected', this).attr('data-edit-url');` with `window.location = $('option:selected', this).attr('data-edit-url').substring(1);` for a workaround.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. This means I have to find different solution as I will not be able to change Rails route.

Comment: No, this is not working. Maybe problem is somewhere else, not in this JS script.

Comment: Ok. Hope you find the root cause. Do update me once you find the problem.